# ASP.NET cookieless sessions only for specific requests?

Tags: asp.net, cookieless

Enabling cookieless sessions via web.config is simple.
Is it also possible to enable it for specific requests (maybe in the global.asax) ?

I need cookieless sessions for a workaround of a problem with IFrames under IE8.
For all normal requests without IFrames I don't want to use cookieless mode.

Is something like this...

```
void BeginRequest (..) {
  if( some-post-or-get-var )
    Session.SetCookieless()
}
```

...possible?

Comment: Could you use asp.net sessions in place of cookies where you have this exception?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you, but it's always asp.net sessions. Either in Cookieless-Mode with crazy URLs or with cookies

Comment: Not exactly.  Check out asp.net sessions state.  Its a way to persist data in memory(server-side).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Comment: @Jeff to a browser, a session is just a cookie. That's how the browser tells the server "it's me, session foo, and not the other person, session bar". Conversely, that's how server knows who is asking for what - "foo" gets "foo content", "bar" gets "bar content".

Comment: @andreas there is another [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5364821/304683) that seems to show a workaround. **However** note my comment about (untested) possible session hijacking exposure - it seems trivial...even MS makes a note of that in [Regenerating Expired Session Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Comment: didn't work for my. I refactored the to code to not use sessions in that specific area of the application. the answer to my question is maybe simply "not possible"